# Income Tax Returns using ITR1 and no TDS2 details available

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, tax-deduction

In ITR1, (Income from Other Sources (Ensure to Fill "Sch TDS2") (AY 2017-18.)

My FD interest, and Savings bank interest, (Income from Other Sources) total below Rs:- 1,90,000/- in (AY 2017-18.)
Since I filled form 15G, TDS is not deducted by Bank.
Hence Form 16A is not provided by Bank.
Since Form 16A  is not provided, TAN numbar is not available to fill TDS2.
Form 26 AS also does not show any deductions.

In TDS2, ( colum No (1) Tax Deduction Account Number (TAN) of the Deductor.).

1. How to fill TDS2 in ITR1 if TDS is not deducted by Bank (No TAN number)?
2. Can we leave TDS2 in ITR1 column blank since TDS is not deducted by bank to file income tax return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fill TDS2 in ITR1 if TDS is not deducted by Bank (No TAN number)?

If TDS is not deducted, you need to keep this blank.

> Can we leave TDS2 in ITR1 column blank since TDS is not deducted by bank to file income tax return?

Yes. You need to leave this blank. You need to pay self assessment tax. For the sum involved you should have actually paid Advance tax. As you have not done these, you will now need to pay penal tax at the rate of 1% and interest at the rate of 1% on the amount of tax you additionally owe.

If you are using Income Tax website of any other website, these will calculate the tax that is due, ensure you pay this and then file the returns ASAP.

Comment: Thanks Dheer sir, for answering this question, god bless you.